# Why is it possible to store a function of the prototype inside a variable?

Tags: javascript

To improve my understanding of JavaScript, I started to read other people's source code. On Github, I encountered [a script](https://github.com/segmentio/utm-params) that has this variable declaration at the top:

```
var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

Later in the code it's used like this:

```
if (has.call(params, key)) {  
    // stuff
}
```

How does this even work? Effectively, `has` is now some kind of alias for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, but why is it possible to store a prototype method in a variable – since it's now a function call, there isn't anything returned.

Comment: Same reason you can do `var x = function() { }; var y = x;` - it's merely passing a reference to the function

Comment: If you are interested in the details of the language, that document will be helpful: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is a first class citizen in Javascript (as is the case in some other languages as well) that means they can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments to other functions as well as returned from functions. There's a good piece on first class functions on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Answer (score 4):

You are not storing the function in the variable, you have just created a reference to the function.